# SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null System.IO.Stream Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, bitmapfactory

I have a question in regards to the BitmapFactory. I am using Xamarin and I'm trying to Decode a stream retrieved from Internal Storage, but whenever I try to Decode with the Bitmap Factory, it does not return a Bitmap. But if I retrieve the EXACT same image from a URL and Decode with Bitmap Factory, it works just fine. This doesn't make any sense, please help!

```
public static async Task<Bitmap> HandleContentImage(Post post)
    {

        var charsToRemove = new string[] { "/", ".com", ":", "-", ".", "_", ";" };
        var ContentImageUri = post.image_url;
        foreach (var c in charsToRemove)
        {
            ContentImageUri = ContentImageUri.Replace(c, string.Empty);
        }
        HomeService homeService = new HomeService();
        try
        {
            Stream CachedContentImageStream = await homeService.LoadImageFromCache(ContentImageUri + ".jpg");

            if (CachedContentImageStream != null)
            {
                Bitmap ContentImageBitmap = await BitmapFactory.DecodeStreamAsync(CachedContentImageStream);
                return ContentImageBitmap;
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] ContentImageArray = await homeService.DownloadImageBytesAsync(post.image_url);
                Stream ContentImageStream = new MemoryStream(ContentImageArray);
                await homeService.SaveImageToCache(ContentImageStream, ContentImageUri + ".jpg");
                Bitmap ContentImageBitmap = await BitmapFactory.DecodeStreamAsync(ContentImageStream);

                return ContentImageBitmap;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try using a Java-based InputStream (i.e. ByteArrayInputStream) instead of the Xamarin/C# wrapped/converted version that is using a .Net Stream (There are some areas that the Xamarin converted streams just do not work properly, but I am not not sure if this is one of them or not)